# Reference request about econometric analysis of Environmental Kuznets curve

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, environmental-economics

I could not find from where to learn the application of Econometrics on data analysis relating to environmental Kuznets curve. Are there any books or articles which talk about the above?

Comment: http://econpapers.repec.org/scripts/search.pf?ft=environmental+kuznets+curve

Comment: panel or time series ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [very good review article by Richard Carson](https://academic.oup.com/reep/article-abstract/4/1/3/1576621) in the review of environmental economics and policy, which (perhaps unfortunately) shows that much of the empirical evidence for an environmental Kuznet's curve is weak at best.